Excel - Increment number based on another cell's value
I have a spreadsheet with two columns.  One column has a list of customer account numbers. I need to create "group numbers" that increment by account number.  The example is what I'm trying to accomplish
spreadsheet screenshot
So the group ID should increment, but duplicated customer numbers should be in the same group ID

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Try using the following formula:


=IF(N2<>N1,N(O1)+1,O1)


Or using LAMBDA() helper function SCAN()
=SCAN(0,N2:N10=DROP(VSTACK("",N2:N10),-1),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y,x,x+1)))


Or, Using XLOOKUP() with SEQUENCE()
=LET(x, N2:N10, y, UNIQUE(x), XLOOKUP(x, y, SEQUENCE(ROWS(y))))


